# How configure Paypal Express Checkout in Sylius?

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, sylius

I've started a new project with Sylius and I'm trying to make an order trying to pay it with paypal. I've changed my paypal account as premium user to get my username, password and signature. Then I've configured the parameters.yml file adding those datas.

```
contexts:
    paypal_express_checkout:
        paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
            username:  
            password:  
            signature: 
            sandbox:   true
```

But when I choose paypal as a payment option I get this:

[image]

Is something else what I have to configure?

P.S. The version of Sylius is 0.11.0-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the live Credentials of paypal please set the sandbox as false in parameters.yml file ... it will help you ...

because if sandbox is true then paypal only allow the Test mode payment